# Importing data into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

http://files.pushshift.io/reddit/requests/Reddit_Election_Raw_Data.zip

Can you please suggest me how I can Import the files in this zip folder into Neo4j?

Comment: I don't think anybody is going to download a 1.2 GB file to answer the question ;) . You might want to provide some examples of what's in it in your question

Comment: Separately, here is a general guide on some ways that you can import data into Neo4j (both with and without Ruby): http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/Miscellany.html

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the format of the data in that big file... have a look at https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/ . Using the Neo4j import-tool you can insert large amounts of data quickly.